# Django: OR with multiple statements

Tags: python, django, orm

I want to fetch an object, sometimes with one condition and some other time adding (OR) another condition.

With Laravel (PHP), this is easy to do:

```php
$q = MyModel::where('col1', $val1);
if ($userWantsToAddAnotherOrCondition) {
    $q = $q->orWhere('col2', $val2);
}
```

At the end I have a query either with condition `'col1' = $va1` or `'col1' = $va1 OR 'col2' = $val2`.

In Django (python), I only know this way:

```py
q = MyModel.objects.filter(Q(col1=val1) | Q(col2=val2))
```

**How can I add the second condition (`col2=val2`) with another statement ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just chain `Q` objects with the logical or operator `|`. For example:

```
cond = Q(col1=val1)
if some_condition:
    cond |= Q(col2=val2)

q = MyModel.objects.filter(cond)
```

Comment: Is `q` the same type as `Q` ?

Comment: @DavidAlvarez: no, `q` is the queryset that you make, so the collection of `MyModel`s that satisfy the given condition(s).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this worked well until I had to `...filter(categories__name='action').filter(categories__name='war')`, in order to retrieve the movies having the category 'action' AND the category 'war'. Doing `Q(categories__name='war') & Q(categories__name='action')` did not work. For the moment I manage it using `Model.object.filter(...) | Model.object.filter(...)`.

Comment: @DavidAlvarez: as in you need *both* categories, or at least one?

Comment: I need *both* categories. Is it possible to achieve with only `Q()` ?

Comment: @DavidAlvarez: then you need to make two filters, so `MyModel.objects.filter(categories__name='action').filter(categories__name='war')`. To the best of my knowledge, you can not do that with a `Q` object. By using two filters, you `JOIN` on the `categories` twice. Whereas for `Q`s, you will eventually make *one* `JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [union()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#union) QuerySet method.

```
q1 = MyModel.objects.filter(cond1)
q2 = MyModel.objects.filter(cond2)
q3 = MyModel.objects.filter(cond3)

q2.union(q1)
q3.union(q1)
```

Comment: Does this only perform one query ?

Comment: The statements using `filter` will query the database but the statements with `union` will just combine the results.